# Select distinct on Capitals and remove uppercase and characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of names in capitals and initials. i have removed the initails and removed the uppercase but distinct still shows them seperate (and it would be nice to get rid of the s of the end of the names.

SQL Oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT (upper
     ( REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '(\S+)$'))) as NAMEZ,
    count(case when daysout is NULL then 1 else null end) as home,
    count(case when daysout is NOT NULL then 1 else null end) as away,
    count(*) as daystotal
    FROM peoplein
```

so what i get from this is

```
johns
johns
john
Jack
jack
```

before the reg and upper I used to get

```
Johns
JOHNS
John
Jack
JACK
```

I would like to just get them to be

```
john
jack
```

thank you for your help

Comment: If someone's name is "Miles", would you also want to remove the trailing "s"? I guess not. So, how will you distinguish "John**s**" from "Mile**s**"?

Comment: I don't get that John / Johns thing. John is a first name, Johns is a last name. Why do you want to change the last name Johns to the first name John? Doesn't John / Johns in your results rather indicate that there are different name formats (like 'first last' and 'last, first') and you need something more sophisticated to get the part you are interested in?

Comment: I don't believe that you are getting a result with your query. It is invalid (missing a `GROUP BY` clause). And even with a `GROUP BY` clause you could not get anything that is not upper case when applying `UPPER` as you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is not a function; it is a keyword that applies to all columns. In this case you want a `GROUP BY` clause instead of using `DISTINCT`:

```sql
SELECT UPPER( REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '(\s|^)(\S+?)s?$', 1, 1, NULL, 2)) as name,
       COUNT(case when daysout is NULL then 1 else null end) as home,
       COUNT(case when daysout is NOT NULL then 1 else null end) as away,
       COUNT(*) as daystotal
FROM   peoplein
GROUP BY
       UPPER( REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '(\s|^)(\S+?)s?$', 1, 1, NULL, 2))
```

or, using simple (faster) string functions:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(
         TRAILING 'S' FROM
         UPPER( SUBSTR(NAME, INSTR(NAME, ' ', -1) + 1) )
       ) as name,
       COUNT(case when daysout is NULL then 1 else null end) as home,
       COUNT(case when daysout is NOT NULL then 1 else null end) as away,
       COUNT(*) as daystotal
FROM   peoplein
GROUP BY
       TRIM(
         TRAILING 'S' FROM
         UPPER( SUBSTR(NAME, INSTR(NAME, ' ', -1) + 1) )
       )
```

*(Although this latter query would trim multiple `S` characters from the end; however, that is fixable.)*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE peoplein(name, daysout) AS
  SELECT 'Abbot Alice', NULL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Abbot Alice', 1    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Baron Betty', 1    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Count Chris', NULL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Count Chris', 1    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Doris',       1    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6;
```

Both output:

| NAME | HOME | AWAY | DAYSTOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALICE | 3 | 2 | 5 |
| BETTY | 0 | 4 | 4 |
| CHRI | 5 | 1 | 6 |
| DORI | 0 | 6 | 6 |

*Note: Are you sure you want to remove a trailing `S` from a person's name?*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/naNiQc9-)

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME!!! I searched for ages and this not only shows but explains it.  I do wish i was smarter with regex I will keep playing online with the tools. I had a real oh wow moment when you said it needs to go in the group by.... i was totally barking up the wrong tree.. fantastic.   this will also help others.. thank you!!!